# pdflatex error due to empty *.pfb file in VSCode with LaTex Workshop

Tags: pdftex, tex-core, vscode, latex-workshop

I'm working with **jupyter notebooks** in `vscode`to export `*.ipynb` files to `*.pdf`. This works very well, but I'm not happy with the generated output. So I decided to make a `*.tex` file, to format it to my distinguished format.

I use

```
$ code --version
1.82.2
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)
Release:    12
Codename:   bookworm
```

and Visual Studio Code LaTeX Workshop Extension, **version v9.13.4**.

With

```
$ jupyter-nbconvert --to latex pdf_test.ipynb
```

I get `pdf_test.tex` and can remove unnecessary things. After this I run

```
$ latexmk -f pdf_test.tex
```

which generates a ***temporary*** `pdf_test.pdf` which I'm able to view in `vscode` after installing `LaTex Workshop` extension by clicking **View LaTex PDF**->**View in VSCode Tab** with the desired format.

From this step I want to build a PDF file by clicking in `vscode` **Build LaTex project**, but this fails. If I view the LaTex compiler log, I get the hint

```
Package rerunfilecheck Warning: File `pdf_test.out' has changed. 
(rerunfilecheck)                Rerun to get outlines right
(rerunfilecheck)                or use package `bookmark'.

){/usr/share/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc} 
</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1095.pfb
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1095.pfb): unexpected end of file
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

and `pdf_test.pdf` is gone. So I tried

```
$ pdflatex pdf_test.tex
```

which ends with a similiar message

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/puenc-greek.def
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/greek-fontenc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-fontenc/alphabeta-lgr.def)
(./pdf_test.out) (./pdf_test.out)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1cmtt.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/jknapltx/ursfs.fd) [1{/var/lib/texmf/f
onts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./pdf_test.aux) ){/usr/share/texmf/fonts/e
nc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}</usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super
/sfrm1095.pfb
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm
1095.pfb): unexpected end of file
```

When I look what's about `sfrm1095.pfb` in `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super`

```
$ ls -l sfrm1095.pfb 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0  5. Nov 2021  sfrm1095.pfb
```

I see an empty file, like the error message wrote before.

And if I inspect `pdftex.map` I see

```
$ pwd && ls -l && grep 'sfrm1095.pfb' pdftex_dl14.map
/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap
insgesamt 9040
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4623455  9. Sep 16:46 pdftex_dl14.map
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      15  9. Sep 16:46 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4621790  9. Sep 16:46 pdftex_ndl14.map
ecrm1095 SFRM1095 " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <cm-super-t1.enc <sfrm1095.pfb
larm1095 SFRM1095 " T2AEncoding ReEncodeFont " <cm-super-t2a.enc <sfrm1095.pfb
lbrm1095 SFRM1095 " T2BEncoding ReEncodeFont " <cm-super-t2b.enc <sfrm1095.pfb
lcrm1095 SFRM1095 " T2CEncoding ReEncodeFont " <cm-super-t2c.enc <sfrm1095.pfb
tcrm1095 SFRM1095 " TS1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <cm-super-ts1.enc <sfrm1095.pfb
rxrm1095 SFRM1095 " X2Encoding ReEncodeFont " <cm-super-x2.enc <sfrm1095.pfb
```

If I run

```
$ cp pdf_test.pdf pdf_test_2.pdf
```

before I build in `vscode`, `pdf_test_2.pdf` resits and I'm able to see it in any viewer.

However, using `pdftex` gives me a messed up pdf file.

Any hint is appreciated how to build from terminal or `vscode` in a proper way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: You are not showing the content of your tex-file, but if sfrm1095.pfb is empty it is obviously broken. Reinstall the cm-super package.

Comment: For comparison, on my system, the PFB is 147K in size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2388/ulrike-fischer) stated, reinstalling cm-super package

```
$ sudo aptitude reinstall cm-super
```

resolves the problems.

Now `sfrm1095.pfb` isn't empty anymore and all other files in `/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super` too.

```
$ pwd && ls -l sfrm1095.pfb
/usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/public/cm-super
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 145929 19. Sep 06:11 sfrm1095.pfb
```